# Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence such that $\lvert x_n-x_{n+1}\rvert \leq 1/n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, does it converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

My attempt to solve this was to use the fact that $1/n$ as a sequence converges to $0$, so, given an $\epsilon >0,$ we have an $N$ such that $\lvert \frac 1 n-0\rvert < \epsilon$ for every  $n\geq N$. Then I have $\lvert \frac1n\rvert=\frac1n<\epsilon$ , so  $\lvert x_n-x_{n+1}\rvert \leq \frac1n<\epsilon$. Therefore $\lvert x_n-x_{n+1}\rvert <\epsilon$ for every $n\geq N,$ and $(x_n)$ converges. My professor told me that it doesn't converge though. Maybe I'm overlooking something or assuming something unknowingly, but I haven't been able to find a fault in my attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only show that $d_n =|x_n - x_{n+1}|$ converges to zero.

The question refers to $x_n$ though.

A famous counterexample here is $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$.

This sequence satisfies the given condition but is not convergent.

Comment: Probably better to use $x_n$ rather than $H_n.$

Comment: I had exactly this idea when I wrote it. Will edit it :-)

Comment: Ah okay, i can see why it doesn't now with that counterexample. I kept thinking 
 of $\lvert x_n-x_{n+1}\rvert <\epsilon $ as converging because i was thinking it was fullfilling the criteria for it to be a cauchy sequence, but i see my mistake. Thank you !

Comment: @Javimaxwell You are welcome :-)